# svn: How to merge two folders into one?

Tags: svn, merge

the problem sounds simple, but I just don't get it right.
How can I merge two folders into one?

Let's say I have this maven structure:

```
module1
  - src/main/java
      - com.app.func1
           - file1
      - com.app.func1.some2
           - file3
           - file4

module2
  - src/main/java
      - com.app.func1
           - file1
           - file111
      - com.app.func1.some2
           - file333
           - file6
```

I would like to merge the whole src/main/java from module2 into module1

After the merge it should look like this:

```
module1
  - src/main/java
      - com.app.func1
           - file1 // it would be nice if the tool would let me visually merge this item
           - file111
      - com.app.func1.some2
           - file3
           - file333
           - file4
           - file6
```

Both modules are already under version control and I don't want to loose the history.

It would be nice if someone could help me.

I've already tried Eclipse subversive/subclipse und Tortoise SVN but I don't do it right.

Most off the time I get some error message like folder src already exists in module1. That is right, but I actually don't care about the folders, they should be integrated like on windows.
Other times through the merge, all the files from module1 are deleted and overwritten with the files from module2.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The script, which is described on http://jv-ration.com/2014/01/merge-svn-directories/ does somewhat similar. You just need to skip step #3, which deletes files from the target folder (in your case, module 1).

After executions of the script, you can use any of SVN tooling to review differences of changed files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to have to do a `svn rename` for each file. You could do script that takes the output of `svn list` to help automate it. You're not going to get it to merge files with the same name though: you'll have to do those manually.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is no easy solution for this silly problem.

As a workaround I moved all my sources with eclipse in the Java perspective.

Mark com.app.func1 and all the folders under src/main/java (maven) and move them with the mouse to module1 src/main/java or use Refactor -> Move

Eclipse automatically does the right thing, it uses svn move and not dumb moving, so the history will not be deleted. Unfortunately you can't move the non java folders because you'll get the error mentioned above (folder already exists  ).

Tip: Both modules must already stay under version control and some SVN plugin must be installed otherwise you'll lose all the history entries.

```
module2
- src/main/java
  + com.app.func1
  + com.app.func1.some2
```